# javascript aray pop no funciona dentro de una función

Tags: javascript, array, funciones

staba intentando un ejercicio aparentemente simple en codewars en el elnguaje JavaScript que tiene el enuncioado siguiente:

> Escriba una función lenR la cual regrese el tamaño de una lista dada. Intente no hacer trampa y provea una solución recursiva.

Mi estrategia para resolverlo es remover un elemento a la vez hasta llegar a un arreglo vacío.

Primero probé en mi navegador si el uso de la función pop podría servirme.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
a.pop();
console.log(a);
```

y concluí que sí, pero defortunadamente al ponerlo en el algoritmo me sale un error aún con pocos datos

```js
function lenR(x) {
  if (x === []) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    x.pop();
    return 1 + lenR(x);
  }
}


var length0 = lenR([]);
console.log(length0);
var a = [1];
var length1 = lenR(a);
console.log(length1);
```

¿Será que la función `pop` no funciona igual adentro que afuera de una función?¿Cómo puedo lograr la funcionalidad que busco?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: x === [] nunca es verdadero, compara `x.length==0` y eliminas el error

Comment: @nerdcoder la idea es implementar length recursívamente, eso que dices sería como hacer trampa no crees?

Comment: mmm si podría considerarse trampa, le daremos otra vuelta :)

Comment: Muy ordinario? `x.toString() === [].toString()` xD es probable pero funciona!

Comment: Así se ve mejor `function lenR(x){return x.toString()===[].toString()?0:x.pop();1+lenR(x)}` :P

Comment: Efectivamente @nerdcoder, una magnífica respuesta, por favor agrégala para aceptarla. Desafortunadamente el ejercicio contiene un error garrafal en la deficición y es muy dufícil pasarlo sin hacer trampa ( cosa que ya había hallado antes y estaba viendo las soluciones )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como solución final para que quede como resuelta la pregunta oficialmente.

```js
function lenR(x) {
    return x.toString() === [].toString() ? 0 : x.pop(); 1 + lenR(x);
}
    
console.log(lenR([]))
console.log(lenR([1,2,3]))
```

Comment: oops, pusiste un ; extra, te recomiendo volverlo snippet siempre para prevenir este tipo de errores, y si pudieras agregar alguna explicación de por qué comparar directamente arreglos vacíos no funciona y cadenas sí... ( algo me dice que las cadenas son inmutables como en Java )

Comment: @RuslanLópez lo siento estimado, por tiempo no alcanzo a agregar la explicación, en cuanto pueda prometo hacerlo!

Answer (score -1):

El error significa que en algún lugar de tu código, estás llamando a una función que a su vez llama a otra función y así sucesivamente, hasta que alcanzas el límite de la pila de llamadas.

Viendo tu codigo haces esta validacion if `(x === [])` me imagino que ahi preguntas que tu arreglo sea vacio pero la forma correcta es `if (x.length === 0)`.

Te paso el codigo con la modificacion

```
  function lenR(x) {
    debugger;   
  if (x.length === 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    x.pop();
    return 1 + lenR(x);
  }
}


var length0 = lenR([]);

console.log(length0);
var a = [1];
var length1 = lenR(a);
console.log(length1);
```

Espero que te ayude, saludos.

Comment: No ayuda, el ejercicio dice "Escriba una función lenR la cual regrese el tamaño de una lista dada", es decir, debe ser un remplazo para `Array.length`, y eso que propones es hacer trampa, por lo que arroja el error `x.length is not a function`